# how to search for a word in multiple pdf files using pdftext in linux

Tags: linux, grep, pdftotext

i have some pdf files in a folder, by using the following command i can able to get the  filename and line which contains the matched word.

```
pdftotext "sample.pdf" - | grep "search-word"
```

but this is working only for a single pdf file, i want to get all the file names in a folder which contains search-word in their content.i don't want to display the matched lines, please suggest me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should list the files matching the pattern:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.pdf"`; do
  pdftotext "${i}" - | grep -lq "search-word" && echo $i;
done
```

The `-q` option for grep prevents any output to STDOUT.  `-l` lists matching files.

Comment: thanks for the reply, in the code you have mentioned sample.pdf again, but i dont want to mention single pdf file name in the code.

Comment: @user2353439 it was a typo (copy/paste error actually).  fixed.

Comment: thanks its working, can i do content search for other file formats like .html, .epub, .doc please suggest me.